# Why not to make Magento StackExchange Platform more helpful

Tags: discussion, suggestion

As you know Magento is hard to grasp for a newbie(especially Magento 2) because there are not a lot of resources(blogs, tutorials) available to learn and get good at Magento.

So when newbie finds difficulty in solving the problem, the approach to this platform and ask solution for their problem. But what happens is, sometimes they get their solution, but sometimes they don't get and sometimes they get the solution when it's too late.

So I am curious, why not make this platform like where the developers with good reputation share knowledge and work like in a tutorial form, so if people find it useful, they cast their votes and give points to them.

It will make life easy for everyone whether its newbie or good developer. It will make this community closer and the developers will learn a lot in a short time.

Answer (score 8):

What you are describing here is a blog.
The stackexchange network works differently.
It's a questions and answers format.
Someone asks a specific question, someone answers it.
If everyone will start posting "tutorials" who's going to validate them?  Who's going to say that the tutorial is correct?
Anyway... self answered questions are not prohibited.
There are quite a few examples in here where the same person who asked the question also posted the answer (immediately or later).
But I don't agree that this website should be turned in a blog format.

Comment: Marius:  I am not talking about turning this platform into a blog, i am just saying, the way people ask question, the same way people share their work. While talking about validating content, why not just allowed good repute developers only share content, and the same why good repute developers reject it, if they find it wrong.

Comment: As I said, self answered questions are not prohibited. As long as they respect the Q&A format.

Comment: OK got your point. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I like this question :)

Yes marius, it is a Q&A platform, but why to answer same/similiar questions again and again?

Wouldn't it be better to link to an approved (wiki) answer?

A very broad question with a self given answer (or suggestions) :P ... [How to write a custom extension?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/how-to-write-a-custom-extension) ...

I think this could be possible for other questions/tags too ... "How to work with collections?" could explain how to filter/sort/limit/join tables/"operate" with collection ... same for blocks, layouts, translation.

I think there is no need to "validate" this ... ask this in a well-formed question and hope that somebody has time for a "complete" answer.

Maybe it could avoid some frequently asked questions?

Comment: For me this comes down to OP first googling before asking the question. Popular questions should pop up on the search results so she or he does not need to post a question.
When it comes to validating answers: wouldn't upvotes deal with that?

Comment: Very valid point IMO @sv3n, I haven't seen a single wiki till now on Magento SE in my around 2 years of being here. I personally find that really weird too, 
 considering the problem of the same questions being asked again and again...